# Python Pandas pivoting: how to group in the first column and create a new column for each unique value from the second column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I am using pandas in Python and I am trying to transform a dataframe. I have a dataframe like this:

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 22 |
| 1 | 23 |
| 2 | 34 |
| 2 | 35 |
| 2 | 36 |
| 3 | 49 |

I would like to group the values in the first column while creating a new column/attribute in a different column for the values belonging to grouped values from the first column. I don't know what is the biggest number of values from Column 2 belonging to a unique value in Column 1.

| Column 1 | Column 2_1 | Column 2_2 | Column 2_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22 | 23 | None/NaN |
| 2 | 34 | 35 | 36 |
| 3 | 49 | None/NaN | None/NaN |

I have been looking for quite a while how to do that efficiently, but I probably lack the vocabulary to find good results. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TRY:

```
df = (
    df.assign(
        temp=df.groupby('Column 1').cumcount() + 1
    )
    .pivot_table(
        index='Column 1',
        columns='temp',
        values='Column 2')
    .add_prefix('Column 2_')
    .rename_axis(columns=None)
    .reset_index()
)
```

As suggested by @Henry, You can directly pass a Series to a `pivot_table`:

```
df = (
    df.pivot_table(
        index='Column 1',
        columns=df.groupby('Column 1').cumcount() + 1,
        values='Column 2')
    .add_prefix('Column 2_')
    .reset_index()
)
```

OUTPUT:

```
   Column1  Column2_1  Column2_2  Column2_3
0        1       22.0       23.0        NaN
1        2       34.0       35.0       36.0
2        3       49.0        NaN        NaN
```